# How to keep earliest record for each category but without considering the extra columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have a data table with 3 columns:

```
Category             Color              Date
triangle             red                2017-10-10
square               yellow             2017-11-10
triangle             blue               2017-02-10
circle               yellow             2017-07-10
circle               red                2017-09-10
```

I want to find out the earliest date by each category. 
So my desired output is:

```
Category             Color              Date
square               yellow             2017-11-10
triangle             blue               2017-02-10
circle               yellow             2017-07-10
```

I've looked through a couple posts about how to do this:

[Finding the min date in a Pandas DF row and create new Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134794/finding-the-min-date-in-a-pandas-df-row-and-create-new-column)

[Pandas groupby category, rating, get top value from each category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880511/pandas-groupby-category-rating-get-top-value-from-each-category)

[With Pandas in Python, select the highest value row for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361599/with-pandas-in-python-select-the-highest-value-row-for-each-group)

and more.

A popular method is the `groupby` method:

```
df.groupby('Category').first().reset_index()
```

But if I use this method, then it'll group by `Category`, but it'll keep both records for `triangle` since it has two different colors.

Is there a better and more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.sort_values(['Date']).drop_duplicates('Category', keep='first')

   Category   Color        Date
2  triangle    blue  2017-02-10
3    circle  yellow  2017-07-10
1    square  yellow  2017-11-10
```

---

If you want to preserve the original order of `Category`, you'll need to sort on a `groupby` call:

```
df.groupby('Category', group_keys=False, sort=False)\
  .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Date'))\
  .drop_duplicates('Category', keep='first')

   Category   Color        Date
2  triangle    blue  2017-02-10
1    square  yellow  2017-11-10
3    circle  yellow  2017-07-10
```

Comment: Should have refreshed the page... But I guess solutions are still not too similar.

Comment: ah i was almost right! but i used "date" inside the duplicates... so i thogutht it was the wrong method. thanks so much for the help, AGAIN!

Answer (score 3):

The following should give you the desired output; compare to what you posted I first sort the values according to the date as you want to keep the earliest date per category:

```
df.sort_values('Date').groupby('Category').first().reset_index()
```

That gives the desired output:

```
   Category   Color        Date
0    circle  yellow  2017-07-10
1    square  yellow  2017-11-10
2  triangle    blue  2017-02-10
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Wen in the comments, one can make this call also more efficient by doing:

```
df.sort_values('Date').groupby('Category', as_index=False).first()
```

which also gives

```
   Category   Color        Date
0    circle  yellow  2017-07-10
1    square  yellow  2017-11-10
2  triangle    blue  2017-02-10
```

Comment: thank you very much as well! this helps me understand a 2nd option. really helpful! choosing the first posted working answer. but i really appreciate your help still.

Comment: adding `as_index ` `df.sort_values('Date').groupby('Category',as_index=False).first()`  :-)

Comment: @Wen: That's nice, will add it!

Answer (score 3):

`head` will return you original columns

```
df.sort_values(['Date']).groupby('Category').head(1)
Out[156]: 
   Category   Color        Date
2  triangle    blue  2017-02-10
3    circle  yellow  2017-07-10
1    square  yellow  2017-11-10
```

`nth` as well:

```
df.sort_values(['Date']).groupby('Category',as_index=False).nth(0)
Out[158]: 
   Category   Color        Date
2  triangle    blue  2017-02-10
3    circle  yellow  2017-07-10
1    square  yellow  2017-11-10
```

Or `idxmin`

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Category').Date.idxmin()]
Out[166]: 
   Category   Color       Date
3    circle  yellow 2017-07-10
1    square  yellow 2017-11-10
2  triangle    blue 2017-02-10
```

Comment: thank you! but the other ones are earlier so i'll choose one from the earliest answer. but i really do appreciate your help still!

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions that is ok , I am here to help :-) happy coding

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions provide you one more option :-)